# Overwrite / replace a shapefile with a new one without losing symbology and shapefile queries

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins, append

I'm currently trying to encourage the company for which I work for to start using QGIS to display boreholes on a map, one of my current problems is updating the data / shapefiles within QGIS for large projects which run for a number of years and include borehole locations and information about them. These projects get borehole locations added to them periodically as site teams complete ground works.

I've created a dataset with custom symbology / legend and separated the boreholes into groups based on a zone within the site. For example Layer 1 - Zone A - Boreholes 1-100, Layer 2 - Zone B - Boreholes 101-200 and so on, this is very simplified but hopefully it paints a picutre.

A way I though I could update the data is, if I get sent a request to add another zone, I could joint the new locations to the already existing shapefile with previous borehole locations. However, if during the import a location is missed the whole process has to be repeated. Instead is it possible to replace ALL of the data within a shapefile (I would take a snapshot of ALL the borehole information old and new, save it in CSV, create a new shapefile, and tell QGIS to use this one instead of the original shapefile as the source of data). Would this retain the queries, layers and symbology of the original layer?

Any other suggestions how to tackle this?

Comment: Unlike CAD, shapefiles don't store symbology. They also don't store queries (that's a layer property). There are at least a dozen flaws in the shapefile format that make it unsuitable for modern GIS use, including the limitation on feature count, which makes your methodology extremely risky. But rewriting the file should not be necessary until it fails completely (at which point it won't help).

Comment: You could consider start using geopackage instead of shapefiles. Together with many other advantages, the can store the symbology.

Comment: Indeed - but be aware that symbology has to be saved separately, it is not saved by default using Geopackage